Robbers double-crossed, daughter avenges her father
So there's this movie I've been wanting to watch again I'll try my best to explain some of it.  
I believe it starts off with a couple of guys stealing something and they all contribute some special skill to it one is a real smart tech guy the other knows about lock he other a good killer something along those lines anyway one of them ends up being greedy and runs with the stolen goods after they all pulled off a mission in the process he kills the oldest of the group and the man has a daughter who's always wanted to get revenge so eventually after time passes the group recruit the daughter and tell her exactly what to do to avenge her father. 
She ends up dressing up as a cable lady and goes into the mans house where he then flirts with her they set up a date on that date she says something that her father used to say and the guy figures out he's been set up then it's all chasing the bad guy after that LOL
Can anyone identify this movie?
I don't think it's older than 2009. And I don't know any of the actors names I believe Robert De Niro might be the old guy but I could be wrong it might have Jake Gyllenhaal but IDK. 

The Italian Job (2003)
Detailed plot summary here on Wikipedia.
Trailer:



Charlize Theron plays the daughter who dresses as the cable girl. Edward Norton is the one who betrays his buddies. And Donald Sutherland is the old robber, and the father of Charlize Theron's character, who gets killed by the traitor Edward Norton. 

Thanks!  I thought it was newer it's way old lol good movie though
